# ¿Cómo mostrar los registros de los ultimos 30 días?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta función donde traigo las ventas del último mes, donde tengo $permiso == 1 debo traer los últimos 30 días para ese vendedor que inició sesión, pero me aparecen todas las ventas. ¿Cómo hago para restringir que para ese vendedor solo aparezcan los íltimos 30 días?

```
    public function pedidoestado()
        {
            $userAct = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $permiso = $userAct
                        ->permisos
                        ->where('codmodulo', 'pedpen')
                        ->first()
                        ->pivot
                        ->permiso;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Aplicar a admin
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            if ($permiso == 2) {
                $datos = vEstadoPedidos::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->get();
//
//-------- que me muestre los ultimos 30 dias, para el vendedor en particular
//
            } else if($permiso == 1) {
                $datos = vEstadoPedidos::where('codvendedor', $userAct->codvendedor)->get();
//
//-------- que me muestre los ultimos 30 dias
//
            } else {
                $datos = array();
            }
            return view('reportesComm/estadoPedidos')->with(
                array(
                    'datos' => $datos
                )
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que unir ambas condiciones, el código del vendedor (probablemente) y la fecha de hace 30 días:

```
$datos = vEstadoPedidos::where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(30))
             ->whereCodVendedor($userAct->codvendedor)
             ->get();
```

Dependiendo la versión de Laravel que utilices, puedes utilizar el helper now() o tendrás que llamar el método desde la clase Carbon: `Carbon::now()`